# Hide first element in array using Handlebars.js

Tags: jquery, arrays, templates, multidimensional-array, handlebars.js

Using Handlebars.js, I am trying to hide the first element in an array. It would be conditional to an option being true/false.

Can this be done without a helper?

Thanks

Horizontal Menu with > as separator

```
{{#if options.display-home}}
 <li class="home">{{options.home}}</li>
{{/if}}
/*If display-home true hide initial separator*/

{{#recursive data "menu-breadCrumb"}}
   {{#if Active}}
{{#if ../../block.Options.DisplaySeparator}}
  <li class="separator">{{../../../block.Options.Separator}}}</li>
{{/if}}
{{/recursive}}
```

Comment: So you only want to show the `<li class="separator">` on the second and subsequent iterations of `{{#recursive}}`?

Comment: Yes second and subsequent. Hide on first and last. Thanks - I have read a couple of your answers to others and am happy to have your help. It seems you have an excellent understanding of data manipulation with this templating library.

Comment: I think you're going to need a helper unless you want to preprocess the data to include some "needs a separator" flags.

Comment: I was thinking that may be the case there. Thank you. Not really sure how those work exactly but I'm working on it...

Comment: Maybe find the `{{#each}}` implementation in the Handlebars source and go from there.